# Logout system in php not working?

Tags: php, logout

I have made a login and register system, which works flawlessly, and I am very proud of, but I cannot seem to get a logout function working.

My login system basically takes the database and scans it for rows that have both the username and password specified, and if it does, then it makes $_SESSION['loggedin']=1; and if it fails it makes it equal to 0.

Once the user is done, he/she clicks on a link that redirects to logout.php, and that is where the issues start. I have put session_start(); at the beginning of each page, but session_destroy, session_unset, and combinations of the two cannot seem to kill the session.

So I am wondering, is there a way that upon loading logout.php, it sets the $_SESSION['loggedin] to 0, and then redirects back to index.php(my homepage)? Which means it doesnt kill the session, but it would effectively log the user out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add your code here...

Comment: $_SESSION['loggedin']=0 and then header('Location:'); in your logout.php?

Comment: Why do you set loggedin to 0? Simply dont set it. You can perform checks like `if (isset($_SESSION['user']) ){ ...  }` to check if someone is logged in. I suggest you search arround for some login scripts to see how they work. Proper login is important for security

Answer (score 3):

### // Four steps to closing a session // (i.e. logging out)

```
    // 1. Find the session
    session_start();

    // 2. Unset all the session variables
    $_SESSION = array();

    // 3. Destroy the session cookie
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
    }

    // 4. Destroy the session
    session_destroy();
```

Comment: The cookie part should not be added. Session_destroy should take care of that

Comment: I didn't know that a session_start() was needed in order to destroying a session. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

if session_destroy doesn't work, use instead:

> unset($_SESSION['put your session in here']);

Comment: Simply do this: `unset($_SESSION);` to unset everything :)

Comment: He does not want to unset the session, he just wants to make it `zero`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// logout.php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 0;
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

It redirects the user to to `index.php`, if `$_SESSION['loggedin']` equals to `1`, and sets `$_SESSION['loggedin']` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have 3 files
1) login.php

```
session_start();
/*if user $_POST username and password is correct then*/
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;

?>
```

2)logout.php

```
<?php

session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 0;

?>
```

3)checkLogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 0 )
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You need to login !')</script>";
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=index.php" />';
flush();
exit();
}
?>
```

with 3 files if you want to control some page that require login before access you just include(checkLogin.php);

e.g. index.php is not require login then not include(checkLogin.php);
but memberProfile.php is require login before then include(checkLogin.php);